# Product of two random Gaussian matrices - orthant probability

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices, measure-concentration, limit-theorems

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} $ be two independent Gaussian random matrices, i.e., with entries independently sampled from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ (a normal distribution with zero mean and unit variance). We define the positive orthant probability $$p_+(m,n,k) \triangleq P(\forall i,j: (XY)_{ij} >0).$$ 
**Question**: How does $\log_2 p_+(m,n,k)$ behave asymptotically, to leading order, in the limit $ n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\alpha m = \beta k = n $, for some positive constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Note that if $n\rightarrow \infty$ but $m$ and $k$ remain fixed, then from the central limit theorem $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}XY$ becomes a Gaussian matrix with independent entries, and then we get $\log_2 p_+(m,n,k) = -mk$. However, I wish to know if how this asymptotic behavior persists when $m$ and $k$ are of similar magnitude as $n$. Specifically, what is the largest positive constant $r>1$ for which we have

$$\lim_{\underset{\alpha m = \beta k = n}{n\rightarrow\infty}} \frac{1}{n^{r}} \log_2 p_+(m,n,k) < 0 \,.$$

I guess the answer should depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Note I relaxed the conditions in this question from the previous version, since I didn't get an answer so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It certainly gets off quite a bit even if $k=2$ and $m$ is comparable to $n$. Indeed, in that case we just need to take the expectation of the $m$-th power of the area of the intersection of two random half-spheres on a sphere of total area $1$. We have a chance like $e^{-nc^2}$ to have it like $(1+c)/4$, which gives an extra exponential factor $e^{-nc^2+cm}$, so $c$ can be of constant size. This effect only magnifies when $k$ goes up.  So, how precise do you want to be (the exact asymptotics may be quite a headache, so you'd better let us know what is the minimum you'll agree to settle at).

Comment: I didn't follow your specific example (e.g., what does $c$ represent?), but I  think I understand the general issue. I've added more information on the required precision of the solution. I hope this is sufficient.

Comment: There is some invariance in the problem, e.g. if I apply the kxk matrix EI which is the identity except EI_{11} = -1 I flip the signs in  the first row, however EI X has the same distribution as X and therefore the prob of being in the positive quadrant is the same as that only the first row is negative.

Comment: Yes, you can flip the sign of any row or column. However, this gives only $2^{k+m}$ options --- this allows us to bound $p_+$ above by $2^{-k-m}$, which is much higher then $2^{-km}$, the behavior I'm interested in.

Comment: $2^{-km}$ is certainly out of question. You can only hope for $2^{-n^r}$ with some $3/2\le r\le 5/3$ but the precision you requested is much higher than given by these trivial bounds so I'm not posting them yet...

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll be happy to understand these bounds you mentioned. In any case, if no exact answer will given to my question, I'll award the answer to whoever supplies the tightest upper bound (non-trivial, below $2^{-k-m}$).